# IIS Express not working after installing VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I've just installed VS2015 on my machine, whilst trying some of the new templates I realised that IIS Express wasn't working.

I tried a previously working MVC solution in VS2012, however this also it now not working.  Before I installed VS2012, this was definitely working as I use it daily.

It will launch Internet Explorer/Edge/Chrome, but in the tab header it just says 'waiting for localhost'.  I've left this for 5-10 minutes and it still fails to find it.

After reading numerous other StackOverflow quesitons, I've tried various settings changes to the application (which I can't remember all of) and deleting the IIS Express directory, but to no effect.

I also created a new blank MVC solution in VS2012 to ensure it was solution related and this is also not working.

Comment: Uninstall IIS 10 Express and reinstall IIS 7 Express to see if you can get VS2012 working. Then you might move on to check what exactly happens to IIS 10 Express

Comment: I uninstalled IIS Express, reloaded my application in VS2012 and the web platform installer told me it was necessary and asked if I wanted to reinstall it.  I did and now it seems to be working again. Thanks.

Comment: Had the same issue. The only way I can get my setup to work is by using local iis instead

Comment: For me the same issue occurs for .Net version 4.5.2 projects.
When I downgraded my project to .Net version 4.5.1 it works.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, but I was using VS2013. Uninstall IIS Express 10 and install IIS Express 8. The download is here:
[IIS 8.0 Express Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34679)

Comment: This worked for me. VS 2015 Enterprise has never worked with IIS Express 10. I even tried completely reinstalling Visual Studio and IIS Express 10 again. I finally found this thread and uninstalled IIS Express 10 and installed IIS Express 8 and it worked first try.

Answer (score 2):

I've been tearing out my hair with a similar issue basically when I create a MVC Web app in VS 2015 and then then build and run it. Eventually it opens in Browser and sometimes works (for a few minutes) then IE 11 seems to freeze and nothing happens, no errors either. 
I eventually found this post and I can say it seems to have worked for me also so a very big thank you. I did the following,

1. Deleted IISExpress folder in Documents.
2. Deleted almost everything in temp folder %temp% (may not be necessary but ...)
3. Went into Control Panel\Programs\Turn windows features off and on and enabled IIS.
4. Launched VS2015 project and opened and ran much faster with no apparent issue.

Comment: I have tried to repair IIS Express 10, but without success; then I uninstall IIS Express 10, and from IIS -> Web Installer Platform reinstall IIS Express 10. and solve this problem. [Note: you cannot load a mvc project without IIS Express]

Comment: Previous comment from antonio was the savior for me!

Answer (score 0):

- Stopped IIS service
- Installed the latest IIS
- Restarted the IIS service and it worked for me